# Cells do not get cleared after TTL is set in HBase

Tags: hbase

I have an `HBase` table with the following description:

```
{
    NAME => 'cf', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1',
    COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', 
    TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE',
    BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'
}
```

I put some values in it and then set TTL (30s) on those values with another put operation. First thing I notice is that the timestamps of the cells get updated after the 2nd put. And 30 seconds later, when I do a scan on the table, I still see those cells in the table, however this time with their timestamps updated to the original timestamps.

I understand that these cells won't necessarily be deleted until a compaction, but why do they still come up in my scan even though the TTL that I set on them has expired?